# Can we realize complete SOA based solution using only JMS provider?

Tags: web-services, jms, soa, esb

SOA is about integrating heterogeneous applications or composing business processes from lower level services.

Can we realize complete SOA solution in a large enterprise where applications cross departmental and ownership boundaries using only state of the art JMS provider that supports both Java and non-Java JMS clients and using web services and  application servers at various integrations points if needed without using more complex ESB product?

Integration architect with good industry experience can best answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - an ESB is not necessary to implement SOA.

Preferably, use Web Services over JMS for implementing your services.

Some issues that are commonly addressed by ESB, that you should be aware of:

**Adapters**

When using legacy service provider or client that don't support the relevant technologies (JMS, SOAP,...) the ESB can act a an adapter for them - in your case all you services and clients should support these technologies them self, or you'll need to implement an adapter.

**Routing**

The ESB acts as a router, hiding the physical address of the service provider.
you should use a strict Queue \ Topic naming convention to ensure consistency and maintainability of your solution.
consider coexistence of multiple environments and versions when planing the naming scheme.

**Service Registry**

You should have some kind of registry with the specs of all services.

some issues that are not easily supported are

**Content Based Routing**

**Central Logging \ Policy enforcement \ Auditing**

Comment: I disagree with this statement saying ESB is not necessary to implement SOA. I heard Rob High (an IBM Fellow) making this comment when some asked if ESB is required for SOA - " It is like driving a car without wheels". The key construct of an ESB is to act as big bridge between service providers and consumers and provide a big level of abstraction. SOA revolves around loose coupling between service providers and consumers and ESB plays the key role in loose coupling.

Comment: I disagree. when you look "beyond the buzzwords" at what the ESB actually does, you will see that it's not much - and many times you can get the same or better results using "lighter" building blocks (like a messaging infrastructure, end point web services technology like .Net and J2EE, etc)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what is in Ophir's answer:

Your question translates as, "can JMS be used for wiring?" Yes, it can be. 
SOAP - the crux of many an SOA solutions - is inherently a messaging protocol. This allows an asynchronous solution, and hence JMS fits the bill. SOAP needs to run on another session/application-layer protocol, which JMS can be.

Envisage the solution as following:

1. Service **providers listen on a JMS bus**, possibly a specific queue/queue+message selector
2. Service **consumers post messages on the JMS bus**, addressing the service they need (particular queue)
3. The response varies based on the requirement, typically a separate queue for response  (possibly specified in the **JMS reply-to** property,) to which the consumer listens to for responses.

In essence, *the service port is a JMS queue*.